# Reformat default heroku log then redirect to output file

Tags: logging, heroku, io-redirection, reformatting

how can I change the default formatting to files (stdin, stdout and stderr) in a Heroku log, and then redirect to output file- logs.txt?

Comment: What programming language? What did you try so far that didn't work?

Comment: I've deployed an app in Ruby and need to change the default formatting of the Heroku's logs using several options. I'm trying to learn how to debug in this environment. I am then trying use an I/O redirection option to save the log output to a file called logs.txt.

Comment: I found similar code that was close to what my question is but don't think it is what I want:

Comment: Figured this out: Used this example and tailored it to what I needed to do: COMMAND_OUTPUT >
      # Redirect stdout to a file.
      # Creates the file if not present, otherwise overwrites it. I wanted to output my heroku log to a file called logs.txt - heroku logs > logs.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out using a command from I/O redirect: Used this example and tailored it to what I needed to do: COMMAND_OUTPUT > # Redirect stdout to a file. # Creates the file if not present, otherwise overwrites it.

I wanted to output my heroku log to a file called logs.txt - 
heroku logs > logs.text

This worked and I found the file - logs.txt in my sublime directory